# Virustotal Trapmine suspicious.low.ml.score

Tags: c#, build

From yesterday, when I scan my exe file that written and built by myself on Virustotal, I get this

> Trapmine
>
> > suspicious.low.ml.score

The full result can be found here
https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/c2c22c7d4769104982ce9dcfc70819ec1ee6fee0ad2a0d428c5e8b2b077b518d/detection

It's very simple C# app, should I worry about anything?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the low ML score is a confidence score, not an actual detection.  Basically if whatever system has not seen enough samples it marks it as suspicious by default, even if no signature or heuristics indicate malware.

Answer (score 2):

No, just ignore it. Had the same issues too with some of my tools. 
That is a false positive.

I guess you know at best, what you codes does.

Answer (score 1):

I checked The link of OP on March 14, 2019 and I found the file is clean
I re-evaluated it, and it's clean 0/69 pass 69 engine including Trapmine

The summary information

```
 No engines detected this file
 SHA-256    c2c22c7d4769104982ce9dcfc70819ec1ee6fee0ad2a0d428c5e8b2b077b518d
 File name  TeachEngine.exe
 File size  419.5 KB
 Last analysis  2019-03-14 07:55:31 UTC
 Community score    +7
```

Every Trapmine ThreatScore results using machine learning have four different outcomes which are:

- clean
- suspicious.low.ml.score
- malicious.moderate.ml.score
- malicious.high.ml.score

For more details [review TRAPMINE Integrates Machine Learning Engine into VirusTota](https://trapmine.com/blog/trapmine-machine-learning-virustotal/)

Ignore it, It's not a real malware, only an evaluation score.